# Is there a sequel to Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy (2005)?

Tags: sequels, the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy

Wasn't there a sequel to [*The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy* (2005)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0371724/)? I can't seem to find it online.

I'm pretty sure that Restaurant at the end of the Universe got made into a film. No? Did I just imagine that? All...so...vividly?!

Comment: Are you talking about the film? With Zooey Deschanel?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I wasn't clear on that but yes I was talking about the 2005 film.

Comment: The 2005 movie has not had a sequel. There was a British TV series done in the 80's which did cover the Restaurant at the end of the Universe.

Comment: Yeah, there's no sequel. Sorry.

Comment: So, I basically, imagined that whole scene from where they were eating at the restaurant at the end of the universe? I'm pretty sure I watched this on TV or something. Was it part of the first film?! I'm so confused. Lol.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're remembering the [80's British TV series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_(TV_series)) which did cover the Restaurant at the end of the Universe.

Comment: @onewho You might want to flesh that out into a proper answer then.

Comment: It couldn't have been. I imagined it starting right where the first one ended. With Martin Freeman, Zooey Deschanel, Mos Def, and the rest of the cast. Even Marvin was the same. Christ, I have these vivid images of scenes from the movie and yet I can't find anything about it online.

Comment: I know what you mean... I swear I remember Marvin being in the parking lot for millions of years... but it's all just wishful thinking... and the fact that I've listened to the radio show so many times :P

Comment: Wow. This is really bugging me. I want to stop thinking about it, but my brain just can't seem to reconcile the images in my head as merely my imagination while I was reading the book. I think I'm going crazy. Hahaha.

Comment: And you're sure they weren't [eating shwarma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Avengers_%282012_film%29)? :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was no filmed sequel to the 2005 feature film adaptation of the "Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy".

Comment: This is because I don't think there _was_ a 2004 film adaptation of HHGG =P

Comment: @rgin typo fixed